# Visual Studio 2013 Facebook comments

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-2013

I developed my project in visual studio **2012**. There was Facebook comments plugin on a page like this:

[image: fb comments example]

I made it by adding app_id and app_secret in app.UseFacebookAuthentication... and adding this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sk_SK/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=***************";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/comments" data-width="600" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

on the page. Problem is when I open **this** project in Visual Studio **2013**, Facebook comments do not show.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Any javascript errors that you see? Kindly add them along with the question.

Comment: _“when i open this project in visual studio 2013”_ – does this happen via HTTP, or is it just a “local” view of some sort? If the latter, then the referencing of the JS SDK via `//connect.facebook.net` will of course not work, because the client has not protocol information to complete that URL. Either replace that with `http://…` temporarily, or test it in an environment where the file gets served via HTTP in the first place.